# Select the li under parent ul only via CSS

Tags: html, css

Let's take this example code below:

```css
/*ul:first-of-type li a { color: red;}
ul > li a { color: red;}
ul:first-child li a { color: red;}*/
```

```html
<ul>
 <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
 <li>
  <a href="">Text</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

My Goal here is to select the `a` tags that are within the parent `ul` tags, but not the `ul` that is nested within `li`.

I have read multiple articles about this but unfortunately couldn't find a solution to do this via CSS.

Can anyone please take a look into this?

Comment: Add a class to the parent ul tag

Comment: can you put in the expected output given the above markup?

Comment: @Gerard tried but didn't help.

Comment: @Sreekanth The expected outout will be changing the colors of `a` tag that is under the parent `ul` and not in the nested one. Here is the screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/Iby6rOP.jpg

Comment: @iSaumya I added an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS below will only select direct `li` children and within them, only direct `a` children.
Since the second `ul` is a child of an `li`, its children will not be selected. It would require the following to select the hyperlinks in the second `ul`:

```
ul > li > ul > li > a
```

```css
ul.main > li > a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
  <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Text</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked like a charm. 

Answer (score 1):

This should only target li's nested one level deep

```
ul > li > a
```

But if not then override this style for the second level ul

```
ul li ul li a
```

```css
ul > li > a { color: red;}
ul li ul li a { color: black;}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
 <li>
  <a href="">Text</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But I don't wanna use `ul li ul li a { color: black;}` this segment. Is there no way to target the `li` under parent `ul` without overwriting the nested `ul` css?

Comment: what is your top level ul inside of? try targeting it like this parentDiv > ul li a{color: red}. this should only target the top level ul, but you may also need to style the inner ul if it inherits the style.

Comment: the parent `ul` is within `nav.navigation` and I have tried what you suggested, but didn't worked: https://jsfiddle.net/fL1v1p6v/5/